# PHP exec() functioning strangely

Tags: php, apache, unix, shell-exec

I am trying to execute `/path/to/script.pl` in PHP; the script, among other things, sends an email when it's done executing. When I try

`exec( "/path/to/script.pl" );`

Nothing happens. Some other relevant data points:

```
print exec( "whoami" );
/path/to/script.pl
sudo -u apache /path/to/script.pl
```

The first, run in PHP, prints `apache`; the second, run in the shell, operates as expected (sends the email); the third, run in the shell, also runs as expected (sends the email).

From this it seems that `exec` is working fine for some commands, and that the script works, and works for the `httpd` user (`apache`). The script itself does no file I/O, but it does access a MySQL database and use `Net::SMTP::TLS` as well as `LWP::Simple`. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: Is your script set to be executed by apache user?

Comment: Yes, it's `chmod 755`; I also thought that `sudo -u apache /path/to/script.pl` would double-check that --- it that wrong?

Comment: Weird... try to chown this file to apache user... I use popen and pclose commands and it works fine. Have you tried to check you php log for error? Remember to activate php error logging.

Comment: I set `error_reporting( E_ALL )` at the head of the script and... the Apache log says "sh: /path/to/script.pl: Permission denied." Even with the user swapped.

Comment: Try using chown apache:apache and chmod +x to file. And let me know if it worked. In your apache config, you can set in behalf of which user/group httpd will execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to [Walter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2293350/walter-macambira) from the comments for telling me to actually check the error logs.

The script was executable (`chmod 755`) but a directory in the hierarchy was `rwxr-x---`; updating this directory to `rwxr-xr-x` fixed the problem. *Every directory* on the path of an `exec()`'d script must be readable by `httpd`.

Problem solved.